# Is Hadoop SequenceFile binary safe?

Tags: java, hadoop, cloud, hdfs, sequencefile

I read the SequenceFile.java in hadoop-1.0.4 source codes. And I find the `sync(long)` method
which is used to find a "sync marker" (a 16 bytes MD5 when generated at file creation time) in SequenceFile when splitting SequenceFile into file splits in MapReduce.

```
/** Seek to the next sync mark past a given position.*/
public synchronized void sync(long position) throws IOException {
  if (position+SYNC_SIZE >= end) {
    seek(end);
    return;
  }

  try {
    seek(position+4);                         // skip escape
    in.readFully(syncCheck);
    int syncLen = sync.length;
    for (int i = 0; in.getPos() < end; i++) {
      int j = 0;
      for (; j < syncLen; j++) {
        if (sync[j] != syncCheck[(i+j)%syncLen])
          break;
      }
      if (j == syncLen) {
        in.seek(in.getPos() - SYNC_SIZE);     // position before sync
        return;
      }
      syncCheck[i%syncLen] = in.readByte();
    }
  } catch (ChecksumException e) {             // checksum failure
    handleChecksumException(e);
  }
}
```

These codes simply look for a data sequence which contain the same data as "sync marker".

My doubt:
Consider a situation where the data in a SequenceFile happen to contain a 16 bytes data sequence the same as "sync marker", the codes above will mistakenly treat that 16-bytes data as a "sync marker" and then the SequenceFile won't be correctly parsed?

I don't find any "escape" operation about the data or the sync marker. How can SequenceFile be binary safe? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clashes are technically possible, but in reality they are incredibly unlikely.

From http://search-hadoop.com/m/VYVra2krg5t1:

> The probability of a given random
>   16-byte string appearing in a petabyte of (uniformly distributed) data
>   is about 10^-23. It's more likely that your data center is wiped out
>   by a meteorite (http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities).